# TelegramApiRequestException при запуске Telegram бота

Tags: java, исключения, telegram-bot, telegram

Пытаюсь создать бота для телеграмм. Класс `Bot`:

```
public class BotStart extends TelegramLongPollingBot{
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        System.out.println(update.getMessage().getFrom().getFirstName()+": "+update.getMessage().getText());
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if(message!= null && message.hasText()){
            if(message.getText().equals("/help")){
                sendMsg(message,"Привет");
            }
            else{
                sendMsg(message,"Я тест. робот");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMsg(Message message, String s) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
        sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
        sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
        sendMessage.setText(s);
        try {
            sendMessage(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "TeenSpiritBot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "TOKEN"; //На самом деле он введен здесь, но я не рискую выкладывать его здесь
    }
}
```

И так же вот код класса `MainClass`:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        BotStart bot = new BotStart();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Почему при выполнении кода из `MainClass` я получаю

> TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook

Что я делаю неправильно и как это исправить?

Ниже все логи:

> org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:32)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
>       at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)
>   Caused by: org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException: Unable to execute deleteWebhook method
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:691)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:53)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:27)
>       ... 2 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to api.telegram.org:443 [api.telegram.org/149.154.167.220] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendHttpPostRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:737)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendMethodRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:733)
>       at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:688)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>       ... 16 more

Answer (score 5):

Из-за блокировок телеграмма ваш бот не может соединиться с сервером.
Можно поставить tor browser.
А затем перед `ApiContextInitializer.init()` указать, что нужно работать через прокси.

Например так:

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "9150" );
```