# Ошибка org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота вылетает ошибка:

> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook

Остальные логи:

```
at org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:79)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:25)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
at Bot.main(Bot.java:28)
Caused by: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException: Unable to execute deleteWebhook method
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:719)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:47)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:74)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to api.telegram.org:443 [api.telegram.org/77.241.16.24] failed: Connect timed out
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendHttpPostRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:765)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendMethodRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:761)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:716)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
... 16 more
```

использую прокси, но все равно не помогает

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "ip" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "port" );
```

Answer (score 2):

[Если прокси не помогли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876285/260756), то поменяйте страну vds, которая у вас была выбрана.

Такая ошибка возникает, когда telegram бот развёрнут на сервере страны, которая блокирует Telegram.